# SharePoint Online native tools - Stuck with 2GB per file limit?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, content-migration

I was happy to see that MS increased the per-file size limit for a SPO library from 2GB to 15GB. However, it seems that uploading data using anything other than the browser is still hampered by this limitation.

I was first noticing this a few months ago when performing a local share migration using the collection of 'SPOMigration' cmdlets from Microsoft; any source file exceeding 2GB was ignored. I figured it was just that the module had some hard-coded threshold and it would be updated eventually.

However, I just tried using the fancy new 'SharePoint Migration Tool' (also official from MS) and noticed it was doing exactly the same thing. It skips anything over 2GB. The logs say

> "Scan File Failure:File size exceeds limit".

Has anyone else noticed this and, more importantly, is it documented somewhere? My clients are asking why they are paying me to do bulk migrations for them, if they end up having to then go back to the browser anyway and manually upload the biggest ones themselves.

Comment: Bump.

I still cannot find anything official saying that the new 15GB per-file limit doesn't apply to programmatic uploads. Also, FWIW, I have never seen (not even once) a drag-and-drop upload succeed for files over 10GB. It will chug away for hours at < 5Mpbs but fails long before it completes. Usually do to basic functions of the local system like screensaver or locking the workstation. It's sort of a unusable feature IMO.